# How to find the number of markers visible in the Map?

Tags: android, maps

I am integrating Map with Google place API. So my requirement is when i zoom out or zoom in the map, the number of visible places(markers) in that map to be displayed in a text view. how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by the implementation of `OnCameraChangeListener`, and pass an instance of it to `setOnCameraChangeListener()` of your `GoogleMap`. Mylistener should be called with `onCameraChange()` whenever the user changes the zoom, center, or tilt. So I find out the new zoom level from the CameraPosition object that you are passed.